How do I figure out pangenome location of hg38 coordinates?
I want to a mapping that has linear coordinates and corresponding pangenome (e.g., .gfa format) locations. For example, this type of information could say that region chr 1 1000-2000 corresponds to nodes 104-108.
I have tried vg find, vg indexing tools, and manual .gfa analysis, but I could not get this information.
Any of these would be a solution:

A description of an algorithm to extract this information from a .gfa file
A file where this mapping is explicitly given
A tool that works to retrieve this information


The keyword to look for is 'liftover'. Here's liftover information for translating from GRCh38 to CHM13:
https://github.com/pangenome/chm13-grch38-liftover
If this isn't what you need, I suggest asking the pangenome people directly via a github issue:
https://github.com/pangenome/chm13-grch38-liftover/issues
